# How do I remove this sentence

Tags: html

```
<body>
<form>
             <div>
                    <label for="email" style="margin-right:72%;">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title="Please enter a valid email address" required>
             </div>
            <button>Send</button>
</form>
</body>
```

How can I remove the output error message sentence "**you must use this format**"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IAVC.png

Comment: What is your purpose? Describe it better please.

Comment: i want to let the output error message only shows ** Please enter a valid email address** but the first sentence is annoying

Comment: As far as I can see you are using some library to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? From the Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/hh673544(v=vs.85)) the tooltip is in the same format.

Comment: See @FluffyKitten answer.

Comment: @CarloCorradini Thats not true, you can easily change the default messages without any library, or even any js - thats what my answer says :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default HTML5 validation message. You can use the standard `setCustomValidity()` function (that is available by default as part of the `HTMLSelectElement`) to change this - there is no need for libraries or even javascript, it is [available in most major browsers by default](https://caniuse.com/#search=setCustomValidity).

**Reference**: [Mozilla MDN Docs for setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity)

This function accepts the string you want to replace the default string with. In your case you want it to display when the input is not valid, so you can add it on the `oninvalid` attribute, e.g.

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address')"
```

FYI, there is a **`type="email"**` for email inputs which saves you from having to specify the pattern for valid input.

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" 
             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address')" 
             required>
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div>

      <!-- YOUR TEXT INPUT -->
      <label for="email" style="margin-right:72%;">Email address</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" 
             pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" 
             title="Please enter a valid email address"  
             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address')" 
             required>


     <!-- SAME MESSAGE ON EMAIL INPUT -->       
     <input type="email" name="email2" id="email2" placeholder="Email2" 
             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address')" 
             required>
        </div>
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title="Please enter a valid email address"
```

from tag input

Comment: If they remove that, how do they validate the input? They don't want to remove the entire message, just change it!